# Bootstrap tabbable nav does not display expected tab in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am developing based on this Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.1'
    gem 'sqlite3', :require => 'sqlite3'
    gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
    gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.2.1'

    # gem for dev only
    group :development do
      gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
      gem 'rspec-rails'
      gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
    end

    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end
```

with this include in my main Style.css.scss file:

```
    @import "bootstrap";
```

And this heading in my application.html.erb file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title> <%= full_title(yield(:title))%> </title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= render "layouts/shim" %>
    </head>

    <body>
    ...
```

(Inspired from Michael Hartl's tutorial)

**I am trying to apply following example from Bootstrap to my design:**

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
   <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
   <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The effect is not what's expected (even if it works fine on their site, and I copy/paste it):

-When first displaying the page, active tab 1 is selected (as expected)

-When I click on 'Section 2' tab, the address bar actually displays the URL ...#tab2, but not the content of section 2. Active tab is still 1.

-When I click on 'Section 1' tab, the address bar actually displays the URL ...#tab1

**What did I miss ?**

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the javascript isn't loading, so your application may not be loading it. You may have forgotten to set your app up to load the bootstrap .js, like so:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/applications.js (or a manifest of your choice)
//= require bootstrap
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the solution, immediately efficient ! I thought that having the bootstrap-sass gem was enough ... apparently not. It is written in applications.js that the file itself should not be modified. Would it be more "lean" to have this require statement in a myscripts.js file in the same folder ? Thanks and best regards - Fred

Comment: I think the advice is specifically referring to adding .js to the file. You should definitely go ahead and change the directives in the file if you need to, as in this case.

Also, make sure you take tagCincy's advice and move bootstrap-sass to your assets group :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for these precisions.

Answer (score 1):

As Zaid stated, it does sound like you did not the import the bootstrap JS.

Also, you should include the bootstrap-sass gem in your assets group.  If it is not, the vendor stylesheets and scripts included in the gem will not be precompiled prior to prod deployment.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I'll add it immediately ! Best regards - Fred